# Play MP3 at Android App

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

> I had **Android** App which play **mp3** but it doesn't play at all.I tested at many devices but I couldn't know why it is not work. please anyone help on this issue.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_elaraby_group);

     WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

     wv = new WebView(this); 
     wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() );
     { 
         setContentView(wv); 
     wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
     wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
     audioPlayer();
     }


}
public void audioPlayer()
{
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp.setDataSource("file:///android_asset/Azan.mp3");
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try use static MediaPlayer method create.

Comment: `but I couldn't know why it is not work`  This says nothing.  What happens?  It crashes?  It plays the wrong MP3?  The volume is zero?  Please explain exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Azan.mp3" is sitting in your `/assets/` folder, try changing `audioPlayer()` to:

```
public void audioPlayer() {
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("Azan.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```